How do I republish compressed video as raw from a launch file in ROS2?
I am trying to replicate this command in a ROS2 XML launch file:
ros2 run image_transport republish compressed in/compressed:=camera/image_raw/compressed raw out:=image

I tried this unsuccessfully:
<launch>
        
  <node name="republish" pkg="image_transport" exec="republish"  output="screen">
    <remap from="in/compressed" to="camera/image_raw/compressed"/>
    <remap from="out" to="/image"/>
  </node>
            
</launch>

I also tried this (which worked in ROS1):
<node name="republishPiImages" pkg="image_transport" exec="republish" args="compressed in:=/camera/image_raw/compressed raw out:=image"/>

I really have not got a clue what is required.  I can't find any examples for ROS2 with google, or even a decent document about the image_transport package in ROS2.

This is what is needed to invoke rebublish from a launch file:
  <node name="image_republisher" pkg="image_transport" exec="republish"  output="screen" args="compressed raw">
    <remap from="in/compressed" to="/camera/image_raw/compressed"/>
    <remap from="out" to="/image"/>
  </node>

Note the args="compressed raw" part.
I struggled to invoke republish from a launch file because there are no examples in the documentation of how to pass parameters to a node apart from using the syntax  <param name="name" value="val"/>
